# Accelerating 2D matrix reading

Tags: c, arrays, performance, matrix

I have a matrix with the size 4*n, lets say for instance (4*3000)
So what is the fastest way to store and read the elements from the matrix

I have tried two solutions that have given me the same time approximately.

1. one array with a size of 12000 elements (2D --> 1D) read by (i+ width*j)
2. 4 arrays with the size 1*3000 and then by using (IF ELSE or Switch case) statement to decide which array i should read

Thus, is there another solution to be used.
Furthermore, how to use the shift technique >> to solve the problem if its applicable for this case

Comment: Didn't you say, they give the same execution time? So what is your question if you have told us the answer?

Comment: I am asking if there is another solution to be used

Comment: A fastest way would be to allocate the space for the matrix in one allocation, then sequentially reading the values into it. That's all there is to it. Regarding all the rest of the minor details (and the 'shift technique'): don't bother thinking about such things.

Answer (score 0):

First technique should be faster.

Also, you can improve performance by accessing elements inside of a loop in a row (...`arr[11] = ...; arr[12] = ...; arr[13] = ...;`...).

Comment: Do you mean reading them manually instead of using the (i+width*j) or when  inserting the values of the elements ??

Comment: @MROF It doest not matter how.

Comment: What about using the shift techniqe >> is it possible? And how to do it ?

Comment: The shift technique aids in computing integer powers of 2 or dividing by 2 but would have little, if any, benefit in array element access unless you are arriving at which element to access by some calculation that can be optimized by that method. I don't see the application to a straight matrix read operation.

Comment: in reading the values .. i read them 8 by 8 from the column of 3000 elements ..
that means: the 4 columns that have the  0,1,2,3 indexes contain 3000 element in each column (matrix of 4*3000).
and i have to read the elements 8 by 8 from the desired column based on the given column name (0 or 1 or 2 or 3) and consider the 8= 2^3 which could be some how converted to >> operation. but i don't know how ?? 
am i right ??

Comment: @MROF You don't need `>>` here.